# Rails application with regular expression validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have created an application like users app using rails. In this app, the text file is imported to DB. In which, i need to validate the mobile number, that means, it should not contains + or * or any other special characters, suppose if it presence it should neglect this special characters and print the rest. I have used the following code to store the text file in array.

```
File.open('text file') do |f|
  while line = f.gets
    array = line.split(',')
    user = User.new
    user.user_name = array[0]
    user.email_id = array[1]
    user.mobile_number = array[2]
  user.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use global substitute using regex, to remove the non-number part.

```
user.mobile_number = array[2].gsub(/[^0-9]/,'')
```